# Prime Factorisation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prime-factoring

I need to write a prime factorisation function that returns an object whose keys are a prime factor and values are the exponents of the corresponding prime factors. E.g.

console.log(primeFactorisation(4)) // { 2: 2 }
console.log(primeFactorisation(6)) // { 2: 1, 3: 1 }

My code so far is below but I'm stuck. Any help much appreciated.

```
const primeFactorisation = (num) => {
    let result = {};
    for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
      if (num % i === 0) {
        result[i] = i;
        num /= i;
      }
    }
    return result
  }
```

Comment: I'll give you a hint: `result[i] = i;` should be `result[i] += 1;` but first you need to check that it is at least 0. Also, inside of the if statement, put an `i--`. This means that the `i++` will be negated, so `i` will be the same when looping for a second time. Edit: A nested `while` loop will also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a number is found, increment it on the result object instead of assigning `i` to the result object.

You also need a nested loop to keep testing for the number until it no longer divides evenly, and you also need `i <= num`, not `i < num`, so that the last factor is caught:

```js
const primeFactorisation = (num) => {
  let result = {};
  for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    while (num % i === 0) {
      result[i] = (result[i] || 0) + 1;
      num /= i;
    }
  }
  return result
}
console.log(
  primeFactorisation(6),
  primeFactorisation(4),
);
```